# Is there is website that explains the game mechanics for Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am looking for a somewhat comprehensive site to explain the game mechanics to me. I have not (nor do I want to) play any other Elder Scrolls game and picked this one up on a whim. Unfortunately the in game tutorial only explains how to move (For those who find this hard to figure out its the WASD keys.. yes this is sarcasm :)).

This game seems even more unexplained than Dragon Age was but there is quite a bit of information out there now about those games so its not so much of a bother.. For this game however, my google searches are coming up with minimal bits of information that leave me with more questions than answers.

Is there a site? Should I just go snag a game guide to get the mechanics explained a bit?

Comment: You could always just ask all the questions you want answers to here? Also I've never played an Elder Scrolls game before, and I picked it up pretty quick just asking questions on here when something confused me. It's a pretty easy game to learn if you learn while playing.

Comment: Haha, I do not think I have the time or patience to put up 20ish questions especially with the 'this is speculative' responses I see to questions that are similar to what I would ask.

Comment: Ah, you edited your comment, hehe.. I have started 3 times now, once was not my choice (stupid game forze) and I have been a dual wielder, a person with a sword and a shield and a person with a spell and a sword and seen almost no difference in game play/progression so its leaving me somewhat confused as to how the game works, thus wanting a more broad view of the game mechanics.. Maybe that is a better question than is there a site that contains the answer...

Comment: My advice is to play the game and when you come across something you don't understand, play for about half an hour more, if you still don't get it, ask a question.

Comment: There is an in-game help menu that appears to serve the purpose that the game manual did for earlier, boxed Elder Scrolls titles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the manual in steam.  To do so go to your library of games and single click on "TheElder Scrolls V: Skyrim" in the left hand list.  That should bring up a page for Skyrim.  You can then click on the [Manual] link on the right side of the page (under [LINKS]).  This isn't very obvious so post if you have any trouble finding it.

You can also find good information on general game play by reading the [Elder scrolls wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skyrim), [Skyrim on Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Elder_Scrolls_Wiki), [IGN guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim), here on stack exchange and by googling for "skyrim beginners guide" or something similar.

*The steam manual is available via a simple link, but I have not included it here as I don't want to support use of non-purchased copies (by people who might find this while searching for the manual). I believe all valid copies of the game should have access to it through their steam client (it uses Steam on PC) or physical copy for consoles/in store purchase.*

Comment: Thanks for the information, not directly a self explaining website but it has helped!