# Best armor type for warrior build?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am a level 11 warrior build in Skyrim and I was wondering what armor type I should use... I started out using light armor because I have a shield and I didn't want to be weighed down by heavy armor, but now I know that you can eventually make each armor weigh 0. I was thinking that maybe I should start using heavy armor now and that it would be a better choice in the long run. my light armor is 15 levels higher than my heavy armor now, but I only spent one point in it.

Comment: The benefit of light armor is having less useless perks.

Comment: @kotekzot If you read my post over at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/48548/8581 you will actually see I advocate taking No armor perks :)

Comment: @James not all armor perks boost armor rating, you know.

Comment: Yeah but I have not needed any more armor rating, or reflected damage, or faster stamina regen and the like.. So I still see no point into putting perks into other areas just for those abilities.. To each their own and all.. I am just pointing out those perks are just not that great compared to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It honestly does not matter. It has been proven [many times](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1313851-complete-character-design-freedom-damage-resist-caps-and-ridiculous-damage-thread-7/) that any type of armor can actually max out the armor caps with just 1 or 2 perks in their respective armor trees depending on which armor you want to use (maxing out leather or iron takes a bit more perks/enchants than say daedric or dragon).

They really do give you the ability to play any way you want and to remain viable. The link above shows the minimum perks needed to max out each classification of armor so you can pick what you want to look like and aim for that end goal.

Comment: the 'many times' link is dead.  But, I think, this is the same thing?  http://www.gamesas.com/complete-character-design-freedom-damage-resist-caps-and-t232634.html

Answer (score 1):

if you want to have little damage then just use heavy armor and the steed stone: fortify carry weight and your armor weighs nothing so like that you can use and train heavy armor without being slowed down.

or just level up more stamina and use a 2 health to 2 stamina ratio.
it also depends if what weapons you use because two-handed does more damage but slows you down because of its weight.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best armor with BASE armor dating is a full set of deathbrand armor, though it's light armor and you need DB dlc, not to mention you have to be level 36 to get the armor

Answer (score 0):

All up if your beginner I would suggest **Dwarven**

Levels 12-16 Go **Orcish**

Levels 16-20 Should probably go for **Bone/Ebony** Or **Daedric** if you don't have any of these stick with orcish until you can smith **Bone/Ebony** Or **Daedric**!

Answer (score -1):

If you have any 3 DLCS And are able to smith nordic that's a good one for begginers

**DO NOT GO BONEMOLD**

Answer (score -2):

I would use any kind; if you are leveled high enough as a werewolf, it won't matter.

Answer (score -4):

If you choose heavy, I suggest using wolf armor. The helmet helps but what I really use is an enchanted hood, which keeps you from losing too much stamina while attacking.

The wolf armor is the best heavy armor you'll find — especially if you are a werewolf.

Comment: I seriously doubt the steel-grade wolf armor is better than daedric.