# What is the most effective way to build a destruction caster / 1 hander character?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character has destruction spells and 1 handed sword equipped at all times.  What is the most effective way to build this type of character?

Comment: That is already the most effective way to do it (and is how my character works) Make sure you hit the Magic Standing Stone, as magic goes up wayyyyy to slowly because of its skill to cost to access ratio (I can just buy a higher level sword and use it, not soo with spells)

Comment: You have a weapon in one hand and a spell in the other.. There isnt much else to building a skyrim character other than simply playing it the way you want to play it. As the common catch-phrase states, you are what you play.

Comment: Nice unoffensive question.. yeah I am nearing on almost 400 hours of gameplay according to steam (360ish hours after this past weekend).. And for the last three weeks I have been playing exactly this type of character, as noted in the comments to @yx's answer.

Comment: Apoc - No one is trying to make you look stupid.  Character building in Skyrim consists of using the skills you want to get better at.  If you want to be a 1-handed/destructon character, simply use 1-handed weapons and cast destruction spells.

Comment: @Apoc Maybe this link where I give a run down of useful/non-useful perks would help as it generally applies no matter which type of character you want to play: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/48548/8581 But yeah, as Origami said, I was not trying to make you look stupid... Thought I was saying you were already on the right path.

Comment: Thank you sorry for the misunderstanding.  I'll just go ahead and delete those useless comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on your objective, *why* did you choose destruction/one handed as the path to take?

The way I see it, there are 3 possibilities:

I. You want to soften them up before you engage them up close.

You'll mostly be focused on your weapon and use destruction simply to spend that mana or else it'd be wasted.  With this strategy, focus more on your one handed perks, smithing (for better weapons, and armor), and health so you can get up close and personal.  Find the biggest and best weapon you can get your hands on, alternate between lightning and/or frost depending on if you are fighting a mage or warrior to drain their mana/stamina.  Putting down some runes/traps ahead of a battle is not a bad idea either.

II. You want to pull out your sword once the enemy gets too close for comfort.

With the right perks (i.e. destruction dual cast and impact), you can literally keep an enemy away from you as long as you can cast the spell.  Your sword really is a last resort that you'd only use when you have no mana left or they're too close for your big aoe spells.  In which case you'll want some nice enchantments on your sword for absorb health and stamina and gear to lower destruction spell cost.  Stun on your sword helps too so you can run away.

III. You want to be the jack of all trades and deal damage no matter what the circumstance.

This is the most perk intensive build as you'll need both destruction and one handed as well as the supporting trees (enchanting and smithing) to make it feasible.  You won't really be great at either as you'll lose the dual cast ability and the ability to bash with your sword and/or use a shield.  There really is no reason to go this path since there are much better supporting spells for a one hander than destruction, but there's no reason you shouldn't since its rather hard to completely mess up a build in Skyrim.

The game's not that hard where you have to min/max everything, just go with it and see where it takes you.

Comment: I actually do all three of those yx, and I disagree with your final statements. I am level 39 with 9 left over perks. I have a crafted daedric weapon and a suit of dragon scale. My spells do very nice damage with the recently obtained 50% bonus to each element and my 1H damage is massive due to all the direct +damage enchants melee weapons get that spells do not. I use spells to blast things at range instead of a bow.. This way I do not have to weapon swap to change between the two and have gotten fairly good at blasting ranged creatures while smashing melee range ones at the same time.